# How to give a param from View to Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a really stupid question. I have a foreach loop in my project:

`@foreach (var item in Model.HallIndex!)`

The foreach gives me all the halls in a cinema + the movies which are scheduled in the future, including the time of the movie. So I get this back from the query to my webapp:

Cinema 1

Now playing:

Next movie: SCREAM (3:00 pm)

Cinema 2:

Now playing:

Next movie: TITANIC (8:30 pm)

Etcetera... I think you get it so far. BUT! I would like to use the Hallnumber to get the result of another query, which gets the movie from the database playing now in each hall. So, I need to get a parameter to the Controller.

**Edit**

This is what I really try to do, but MovieNow doesn't work:

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IndexViewModel>> Index(int hallId)
{
   IndexViewModel indexViewModel = new IndexViewModel();
        
   indexViewModel.MovieIndex = MovieIndex();
   indexViewModel.MovieNow = MovieNow(hallId);
   indexViewModel.HallIndex = MovieNext();

   return View(indexViewModel);
}

public Showtime MovieNow(int hallId)
{
return _context.Showtime.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM db.\"Showtime\" S JOIN db.\"Movie\" M ON S.\"MovieId\" = M.\"Id\" WHERE \"StartAt\" < now() AND S.\"HallId\" = {0} ORDER BY \"StartAt\" DESC", hallId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public Hall? Hall { get; set; }
    public Movie? Movie { get; set; }
    
    public IEnumerable<Showtime>? MovieIndex { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Showtime>? HallIndex { get; set; }
    public Showtime? MovieNow { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="col-4">
   <div class="text-center index-hall-overview">
   @foreach (var item in Model.HallIndex!)
   {
      <div class="row">
         <p class="index-hall-title">CINEMA @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.HallId)</p>
         <p class="index-hall-now">Now playing: @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.MovieNow.Movie.Title, item.HallId) </p>
         <p class="index-hall-next"><span class="index-hall-p">Next movie:</span> @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Movie.Title)
         @{
             var startTime = item.StartAt.ToLocalTime().TimeOfDay.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
         }
         (@Html.DisplayFor(model => startTime))</p>
         </div>
         <hr class="index-hall-hr"/>
         }
    </div>
</div>
```

If I do this, I get the error:
"PostgresException: 42702: column reference "Id" is ambiguous POSITION: 8"

Comment: Why use `DisplayFor` for this?

Comment: I dunno, It is for my school assignment. My first steps into C#. What do you recommend?

Comment: Why not simply `@MovieNow(i)` in the cshtml?

Comment: Just @MovieNow(i) ? That really doesn't work.
It says: "Cannot resolve symbol "MovieNow"
And if I write: ```@Model.MovieNow(1);```I get the error: "Method, delegate or event is expected"

Comment: @iFritsWester What are you trying to achieve here? Can you show us more code so we can go through your problem in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are joining the Showtime and Movie tables, the `SELECT *` will return all columns from *both* tables. And apparently both contain an Id column, so which should be used to fill an Id property?

Solution: limit the columns returned to the one correct table by using `SELECT s.*`

Comment: Thank you, that resolved the error and the page loads. But I think I do something wrong in this syntax of this line. It returns nothing now:


```@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.MovieNow.Movie.Title, item.HallId)```

Comment: And when I change the returntype from showtime in IQuerable<Showtime> it returns this error: "NpgsqlOperationInProgressException: A command is already in progress: MY QUERY".

Comment: I assume you did remove the .FirstOrDefault() when you want to get the IQueryable?

Comment: As for the display-line, what if you use just `@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.MovieNow.Movie.Title)` (so remove the HallId)?

Comment: But, how does he know which hall? I have to give him the param right?

Comment: It now gives me the error:

NpgsqlOperationInProgressException: A command is already in progress: SELECT x.* FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "HallId" ORDER BY "StartAt") rn FROM db."Showtime" where "StartAt" > now()) x JOIN db."Movie" M ON "MovieId" = M."Id" WHERE x.rn = 1 ORDER BY "HallId"

Comment: Could it be [this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1077)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242589/discussion-between-ifritswester-and-hans-keing).

Comment: Fixed it by putting all data from the query in a List and then call the data by calling indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because you're pointing to the same  ID in the view `DisplayFor(model => item.HallId)`.

Comment: The problem was that there were 2 tables joining, both with id as PK. I solved that problem, no error, but still no return value. The query is not the problem. In the Query Tool it returns the right row

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are passing right parameters,becuase your code looks good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [FromSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) takes care of the parameters, the way the OP has coded it - so no worries in this case